# Cannot upload image taken from Camera in android WebView [Can upload image from gallery]

Tags: android, file, webview, android-webview

I developed website and converted it into Android app using WebView. Saw few implementation and tried FILE upload, where I can upload image from gallery but I am not allowed to upload image which is taken from Camera. I was thrown net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED error. Please help me to get this fixed.

MAINACTIVITY.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView web;
    String webUrl = "https://mywebsite.com/";


    public Context context;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private ValueCallback<uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myweb);
        web.loadUrl(webUrl);

        WebSettings mywebsettings = web.getSettings();
        mywebsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mywebsettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebsettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        mywebsettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mywebsettings.setSavePassword(true);
        mywebsettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        mywebsettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);


        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }

                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                return true;
            }

            private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

                File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                imageStorageDir = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                return imageStorageDir;
            }

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                try {
                    File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); // save to the private variable

                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                    

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");

                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

        });
    }

    

    verride
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }

                Uri result = null;

                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }

        } 

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                    // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;

        } 
        

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(web.canGoBack()){

            web.goBack();
        }
        else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

using following app permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2"/>
```

strings.xml

```
  <string name="image_chooser">File Chooser</string>
```

Comment: You need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> `

Comment: Tried that too, but it didn't helped me, tried in ask version 30 and 29.

Comment: Your problem is here `File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");`. `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated. The easiest way is to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `<application>` element in the manifest.